Counting orbits of permutation group acting on bit strings
Let $ G $ be a subgroup of $ S_n $. What is the the best way to count the number of orbits of $ G $ acting on the length $ n $ bit strings $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $?
Obviously permutations can only take a bit string to another bit string of the same Hamming weight, so a lower bound for the number of orbits is $ n+1 $, the number of possible Hamming weights
If $ G=S_n $ then the lower bound is saturated and there are $ n+1 $ orbits, one for each weight.
If $ G=A_n $, for $ n\neq 2 $, then again there are $ n+1 $ orbits, one for each weight.
In particular what I am using is that if $ G $ is $ k $-transitive then all bit stings of Hamming weight $ k $ will form a single orbit, and also all bit strings of Hamming weight $ n-k $ will form a single orbit.
But what about for general $ G $ is there a good way to count the number of orbits? Say for example a systematic way to count in the case that $ G $ is cyclic generated by an $ n $ cycle?
A particular case I'm interested in is counting the number of orbits of the $ 5 $-transitive group $ M_{24} $ acting on $ \mathbb{F}_2^{24} $.
I'm equally interested in answers that use theory and answers that are computational, like GAP

I see there is a downvote, do you have any suggestions about how to improve the question? Should I add more background? Make the question narrower? Does this have a well known or obvious answer that I am missing? Is there a factual error I can correct?

I might be wrong but isn't this just the cycle index evaluated with all variables set to two?

Since you are asking how to do this in GAP
gap> g:=MathieuGroup(24);;
gap> ci:=CycleIndex(g);
1/244823040*x_1^24+1/21504*x_1^8*x_2^8+1/1080*x_1^6*x_3^6+1/7680*x_2^12+1/128\
*x_1^4*x_2^2*x_4^4+1/60*x_1^4*x_5^4+1/24*x_1^2*x_2^2*x_3^2*x_6^2+1/384*x_2^4*\
x_4^4+1/504*x_3^8+1/21*x_1^3*x_7^3+1/16*x_1^2*x_2*x_4*x_8^2+1/96*x_4^6+1/11*x\
_1^2*x_11^2+1/7*x_1*x_2*x_7*x_14+2/15*x_1*x_3*x_5*x_15+1/20*x_2^2*x_10^2+1/12\
*x_2*x_4*x_6*x_12+1/24*x_6^4+2/23*x_1*x_23+2/21*x_3*x_21+1/12*x_12^2
gap> Value(ci,List([1..24],x->X(Rationals,x)),List([1..24],x->2));
49

The cycle index is a polynomial, create the variables needed, and evaluate.

Does GAP have anything like necklace polynomials/ generalized necklace polynomials for doing this in the the cyclic case?

Not built in. But the basic tools are in.

Is there a way to count the number of orbits of a given size? For example all the orbits of size $ 24 $ for the action of $ M_{24} $ on $ \mathbb{F}_2^{24} $? I guess what I'm saying is is there an easy way to produce a list of all the sizes of each of the $ 49 $ orbits, and see how many orbits of size $ 24 $ there are? If this is better suited to a new question I can also just do that

I'd never heard of the cycle index of a permutation group before so I really appreciate the comment from Marko Riedel! I did some reading and Marko is indeed right that what I want is just the cycle index evaluated with all variables set to $ 2 $.
So for example the action of $ M_{24} $ on $ \mathbb{F}_2^{24} $ has $ 49 $ orbits.
And the action of $ M_{12} $ on $ \mathbb{F}_2^{12} $ has $ 14 $ orbits. We can kind of check this by hand because 5 transitivity means that all orbits are weight classes except weight 6 which must split into at least two orbits and indeed it splits into exactly 2 so we have $ 6+2+6=14 $
As for counting for cyclic permutation group this can be done the same way using the cycle index, but there is a special name for this, the cycle index polynomials you get this way are called necklace polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial
In general its always great to see a beautiful new area of math and I'm a stranger to combinatorics so I'm excited to learn more about cycle index polynomials! Thanks so much Marko Riedel!

Glad I was able to help. Concerning Wikipedia I think you want what they call a general necklace polynomial as you do not exclude repeated patterns. Some auxiliary reading.
